# Remove a library from .libPaths() permanently without Rprofile.site

Tags: r

## How can I permanently remove a library in R?

```
.libPaths()
[1] "\\\\per-homedrive1.corp.riotinto.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"                                            
[3] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

The first item is my corporate "My Documents" folder, and the apostrophe in the path from my surname is causing all kinds of grief when using `R CMD INSTALL --build` on a package I'm making, not to mention issues using packages installed there when I'm offline from the network.

I want to use `C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library` as the default instead, but I don't want to have to rely on an `Rprofile.site`.

### What I've tried

```
> .libPaths(.libPaths()[2:3])
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library" "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

That seems to work, but only until I restart my R session, and then I'm back to the original .libPaths() output...

```
Restarting R session...

> .libPaths()
[1] "\\\\per-homedrive1.corp.riotinto.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"                                            
[3] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

I thought maybe `.libPaths()` was using `R_LIBS_USER`

```
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "//per-homedrive1.corp.riotinto.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15"
```

So I've tried to unset it using `Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER")` but it doesn't persist between sessions.

### Additional Info

If it matters, here are some environment variables that might be relevant...

```
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2"
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2"
> Sys.getenv("R_USER")
[1] "//per-homedrive1.corp.riotinto.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell"
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "//per-homedrive1.corp.riotinto.org/homedrive$/Tommy.O'Dell/R/win-library/2.15"
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_SITE")
[1] ""
```

I've tried `Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER")` but this also doesn't stick between sessions

Comment: Since it is in an R character value, I would have suggested trying to escape the single-quote.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just set the environment variable `R_LIBS` in Windows to something like

```
R_LIBS=C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library
```

Restart R.

Comment: Setting this path variable helped for me instead: R_LIBS_USER

Comment: a working example looks like this

Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_USER = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library')

Comment: This just appended it to the problematic ones instead of replacing for me. I solved it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873741/13210554) answer instead.

Answer (score 23):

This is bit late response to the question, but might be useful for others. 
I order to set up my own path (and remove one of the original ones) I have:

- used `.libPaths()` inside **R** to check *current library paths*;
- identified which paths to keep. In my case, it kept **R**'s original library but removed link to my documents.
- found **R-Home** path using `R.home()` or `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")`;

  - `R-Home\R-3.2.2\etc\Rprofile.site` is **read every time R kernel starts**. Therefore, **any modification will be persistent to every run of R**.
- Edited `Rprofile.site` by adding the following,

`.libPaths(.libPaths()[2])
.libPaths("d:/tmp/R/win-library/3.2")`

**How it works?**

- First line remove all but one path (second from the original list), the second line adds an additional path. We end up with two paths.
- note that I use Unix path notation despite using windows. R always use Unix notation, regardless of operating system
- restarted R (using `Ctr+Shift+F10`)

This will work every time now.

Comment: This answer really helpful, but as far as I understand by executing `.libPaths("d:/tmp/R/win‑library/3.2")` after `.libPaths(.libPaths()[2])` you are setting only _"d:/tmp/R/win‑library/3.2"_ as a path, so first setting will be overridden.

Comment: Not really - I first remove all but second path using  '.libPaths(.libPaths()[2])'  and then add  `.libPaths("d:/tmp/R/win-library/3.2")` as an aditonal path. I end up with two paths.

Comment: it's not so obvious, I added comment to my original text

Comment: This is not true on `ubuntu`: running `.libPaths(.libPaths()[2])` does not remove other libs.

Comment: At least for R 3.5.2, according to .libPaths help document, it will only add parameter to existing path, not replacing existing paths. "If called with argument new, the library search path is set to the existing directories in unique(c(new, .Library.site, .Library))"

Answer (score 11):

Use this function in `.Rprofile`

```
set_lib_paths <- function(lib_vec) {
  lib_vec <- normalizePath(lib_vec, mustWork = TRUE)
  shim_fun <- .libPaths
  shim_env <- new.env(parent = environment(shim_fun))
  shim_env$.Library <- character()
  shim_env$.Library.site <- character()
  environment(shim_fun) <- shim_env
  shim_fun(lib_vec)
}
set_lib_paths("~/code/library") # where "~/code/library" is your package directory
```

Original Source: https://milesmcbain.xyz/hacking-r-library-paths/

Comment: This is the correct procedure for removing an R library from the operating system when you do not have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I have put the `Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER")` command in a `.Rprofile` file in my windows `"own documents"` folder. Seems to help. My problem was that being in an active directory environment made `R` upstart and package loading incredibly slow when connected via vpn.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this at `RProfile` file (@`library/base/R/`), you can search the lines where `R_LIBS_*` environment variables are set (for e.g. `Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_SITE=....)` and `Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_USER=.....)`)
You can also search the code `.libPaths()`, which sets the library tree. So you can achieve your goal by a combination of commenting, unsetting and setting the `R_LIBS` variables before the `.libPaths()` call as you wish. For e.g. Something like:

```
Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS")
Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER")
Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_SITE = "D:/R/libs/site")
Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_USER = "D:/R/libs/user")
Sys.setenv(R_LIBS = "D:/R/libs")
```

Comment: has been some time since original question, but I have just done this and it was needed to put the Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER") line for changes to take effect. Upvoting