# How to change .Rprofile location in RStudio

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio, rprofile

I am working with a "factory fresh" version of RStudio on Windows 7. R is installed under `C:/Program Files` which means the default libraries are stored here, and the two locations contained in `.libPaths()` on startup are both within this folder.

I want to work with another R library (igraph). Since the `C:\Program Files` folder is write-protected, I have set up another area to work in: `C:\Users\nick\R` and installed the igraph library in `C:\Users\nick\R\library`. I can manually add this location to the `.libPaths()` variable and use the library with no problems.

However, my problem is getting RStudio to automatically add this location to the `.libPaths()` variable on startup. I read that I could add the relevant command to my .Rprofile file - but I couldn't find any such file (presumably they are not automatically created when RStudio is installed). I then created a file called .Rprofile containing only this command. This only seemed to work when the .Rprofile file was saved in `C:\Users\nick\Documents` (which is the path stored in both the R_USER and HOME environmental variables). What I would like is to have the .Rprofile file stored in `C:\Users\nick\R`.

I have read all the information in ?Startup and it talks about where to store commands that run on startup. But I just can't make this work. For example there seems to be no way to change the location of the home directory without reading a file stored in the home directory. I don't seem to have any .Renviron files and creating these myself doesn't seem to work either.

I would really appreciate an answer in simple terms that explains how I could go about changing where the .Rprofile file is read from.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217758/remove-a-library-from-libpaths-permanently-without-rprofile-site/15218299#15218299) help?

Comment: It looks like it might if I understood it :-) Am I supposed to run an R_LIBS=xxx command using cmd in Windows (i.e. outside of R)?

Comment: yous set windows environment variable. (panel settings...)

Comment: Thanks - this has done the trick for adding a new library path. My specific issue appears to be solved. Would still be interested in how the .Rprofile file can be relocated though

Comment: .Rprofile is set through R_USER  at the begining of session. SO what is your question?

Comment: In that case I suppose the question must be how to change what is stored in R_USER. Can this also be done through windows control panel?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, you set the R_USER profile by opening up a command line and running:

```
SETX R_PROFILE_USER "C:/.../.Rprofile"
```

Where (obviously) the path is the path to your desired .Rpofile. In R, you can check that it worked:

```
Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")
```

Should return the path you specified. Note that you likely need to have all R sessions closed before setting the R_USER variable.