# Setting R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS does not delete original Program Files library path

Tags: r

I have the following problem (I am aware that there are many questions dealing with setting a new library path, such as [Changing R default library path using .libPaths in Rprofile.site fails to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work/19662905#19662905) or [Remove a library from .libPaths() permanently without Rprofile.site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217758/remove-a-library-from-libpaths-permanently-without-rprofile-site), and I have read all of them, but did not find an answer to my specific problem):

I want to avoid the dialogue box prompting me to set a personal library, because the library folder in *Program Files* tends to cause problems.

To do so, I set the environment variables `R_LIBS` and `R_LIBS_USER` in the Control Panel to `"C:/Users/deca/Desktop/packages"`.

However, R still returns the Program Files library folder (both in R GUI and RStudio):

```
> print(.libPaths())
[1] "C:/Users/deca/Desktop/packages"    "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"
```

Even worse, when trying to install new packages, R keeps asking me to set a personal folder, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid by defining `R_LIBS` and `R_LIBS_USER`.

I also tried to only select the first path via `.libPaths(.libPaths()[1])`, but no matter what I try R keeps both paths.

I want to only have one single folder for my packages, `C:/Users/deca/Desktop/packages`. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe easiest would be if you'd install R somewhere under `C:/Users/deca/...` if that could solve your problem? Else if you want a single library path you'd somehow have to duplicate all the packages that come with base R (like stats, utils, methods etc - and base too?!) - and I have never tried whether that's even possible

Comment: @RolandASc I did that, and it works, thanks! I was just wondering if there is a way to keep the installation "as-is".

Comment: I am having similar problem. In my case, I installed some package in my own R_LIBS_USER=/$HOME/myR, the environment variable is exported from my .bashrc file. And you can clearly see it (echo $R_LIBS_USEr display the correct directory). But when I launch R, the path is not pre-panded to the result of .libPaths() result.  I don't know what got changed on my system (Centos), it used to work perfectly.  Look all over the place did not see any one posted a solution.