# Leaving one library path for R on ubuntu

Tags: r

I am using `ubuntu 14.04`. I want to set up myself just one library path for `R` where all of the packages would be installed. I tried setting up environment variables `R_LIBS`, `R_LIBS_USER` in `.bash_profile` (of course running `source ~/.bash_profile` afterwards), tried adding `.libPaths(.libPaths()[1])` to `Rprofile.site`, but the only thing that I achieve is that my own library is added to `3` other already present ones. Due to this I am getting errors when some packages are from other `R` version that was previously installed. I want to leave just one library path and prevent `R` from searching in all others. I found several threads about the issue but neither of them worked for me:

[Remove a library from .libPaths() permanently without Rprofile.site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217758/remove-a-library-from-libpaths-permanently-without-rprofile-site)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/reinstalling-packages-on-new-version-of-r/7670

I can try just uninstalling all of the packages and reinstalling them over, but I kind of want everything to be structured and organized anyway. I do not like very much that `R` shuffles libraries into different folders and want to have just one or max two that were defined solely by me.

Comment: You should try modifying [R_LIBS_SITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387660/how-to-change-libpaths-permanently-in-r).

Comment: That almost worked: I set this environment variable, but still one path remained: `/usr/lib/R/library`

Comment: That should be your `base` library. The other one you specified is essentially your `repo` sourced library. See the [Debian R policy](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#debian-r-policy) for specifics.

Comment: https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#renviron

Comment: I can not eliminate the last base library still, and so probably that is the reason why I can not fix the error of the R packages installed for the previous version of R.