# how to set lib-paths in R to have a single directory which is "C:\Users\Username\Documents\..."

Tags: r, rstudio, library-path

*Win 7 64 bit machine
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)*

Question: How do I set my library paths to  have only one directory, namely:
*"C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"*
?

I added .libPaths("C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5")
to *RProfile.site*

Set *R_LIBS_USER* and *R_LIBS* to:
*C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\win-library\3.5*

R_LIBS_SITE:

```
[1] "C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.5"
```

yet when I start RStudio and input:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library"
```

I still end up with two library paths (as above).

Furthermore, in *RStudio* I am not able to *set* lib-paths to just "C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" with these steps:

```
> .libPaths("C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5")
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library" 
> .libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library")
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library"
> .libPaths("C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5")
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library"
```

An attempt to set lib-paths by editing *.Renviron* with:

```
> usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

Added .libPaths("C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\win-library\3.5") to
and saved *.Renviron* file. This resulted in an *R Message* upon restarting *R*:

*File C:/Users/Username/Documents/.Renviron contains invalid line(s)
.libPaths("C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\win-library\3.5")*

Thank you

Comment: You can't, and you don't want to, remove the base library location. That's where R's own packages live, and without them you can't use R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217758/remove-a-library-from-libpaths-permanently-without-rprofile-site seems to imply to the contrary. Many of the steps above are from this thread. thanks

Comment: That question is about removing a _user-specific_ directory, not the base R install directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hong Ooi's answer: "You can't, and you don't want to, remove the base library location. That's where R's own packages live, and without them you can't use R."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .Renviron, can you try it with Rprofile?

in the RStudio console window:

```
usethis::edit_r_profile()
```

This will open the .Rprofile file, located in the default R_USER folder

In the RStudio code window, write (or add) the following, then save:

```
.libPaths(c("C:/R/Library", .libPaths()[-1]))
```

This code replace the first element of the libPaths list with the "C:/R/Library" value. Restart RStudio, and you're done. You can check it by typing `.libPaths()` in the console window.

As for the second element of the list ("~/R/R-4.1.2/library" or the like), you cannot remove it as it contains R own packages.